# How to use a bash variable with special characters

Tags: bash

I have just written a bash script to check a password using the haveibeenpwned.com API and I came across an issue. The first line of my script looks like:

`hash=$(printf "$1" | sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1)`

Which works fine as long as the password doesn't contain any bash special characters.

I was wondering if there was a way to escape every special character in a bash variable so that a user could enter `asdf(*&^%` as their password?

Thanks